# "accepted" answer on Apple.SE about page is actually the least-voted one

Tags: bug, status-completed, tour

On the [Apple.SE about page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/about), this answer is shown as accepted in the example question:

[image: about page screenshot]

But that answer ("in my business we reatinoalize...") has only one vote in reality, making it the third-most voted answer:

[here's a link to the question itself.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40355/can-i-see-which-ipad-apps-i-use-most-frequently)

[image: question screenshot]

Comment: It's a secret communist message (about renationalization)

Comment: Seriously though, it's arguably not the best example to use. Not a big deal but still worth fixing

Comment: It's a lot better than the last example (which was dead wrong) - see http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1892/the-accepted-answer-of-the-ask-different-example-question-is-wrong

Comment: I have updated the question to be a better (I think) example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very much intentional. The example question and answers are not meant to be *accurate* - they're meant to demonstrate the workings of the system. If you look at it *before* the system adds the checkmark, both answers are at a score of three.

[image: Two answers before]

In order to demonstrate the actions of upvoting and accepting an answer (and how that causes an answer to change positions), the second answer is upvoted and accepted which causes it to rise above the first. This happens when you scroll down the page far enough.

The questions (and answers) which appear on that page are randomly selected and automatically change after some unknown interval of time. Obviously one of the criteria is a question that has *at least* two answers, and it just selects two random answers out of that question for the demonstration.

You'll also notice that the answer in your screenshot has a score of 4 and a checkmark, while it's listed as having a score of 9 down in the section that talks about editing.

Comment: That makes sense, though it seems a little strange. Will accept in 5 mins